# Validate List Loop not referencing between sheets, error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, loops, validation

Below is a code that should loop through each sheet and apply data validation (for several columns per sheet). It works for the first sheet but not for the following and delivers the error code 1004 when it comes to `Set ValidationRange = Worksheets(Works.Name)` like if it could not reference it properly.

I tried many different ways to code it, following many suggestions.

```
Sub loopValidateTest()
Dim Works As Worksheet

For Each Works In Sheets
    If Works.Name <> "Bilan_H" Then

        For ColumnList = 2 To 16
            Set ValidationRange = Worksheets(Works.Name).Range(Cells(1, ColumnList), Cells(46, ColumnList))

            If IsEmpty(Cells(1, ColumnList)) = False Then
              With Worksheets(Works.Name).Range(Cells(48, ColumnList), Cells(2000, ColumnList)).Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=" & ValidationRange.Address
              End With
           End If

        Next ColumnList
    End If
Next Works

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Set ValidationRange = Worksheets(Works.Name).Range(Cells(1, ColumnList), Cells(46, ColumnList))
```

unless you explicitly specify otherwise, cells assumes the current active worksheet. It should be

```
 Set ValidationRange = works.range(works.cells(1,columnlist),works.cells(46,columnlist))
```